# Vector of Vector of (member) function pointers

Tags: c++

I'm constructing an simple listener / callback mechanism, for my current experimental project.  And i'm stuck with implementing a container structure what seems should be vector of vector of pointers. I choose this way because i want the root vector to simple have KEY of event type let's say is an enum (int), then at this key i want to store vector of pointers to available methods for this event type. In logical representation something like:

```
[EVENT_TYPE_QUIT]
                 [ptr1]
                 [ptr2]
                 [ptr3]
                 [ptr4]
                 [....]
[EVENT_TYPE_HELLO]
                 [....]
                 [....]

typedef enum {
   EVENT_TYPE_QUIT,
   EVENT_TYPE_HELLO,
   ...
} EventType;
```

So the simplified implementation looks something like this (it's an template in reality but imagine T is any user type you can map an event).

```
class EventMapper {
    ...

    typedef void (T::*functionPtr)(); // simple pointer to T member function with no args.

    std::vector< std::vector<functionPtr> > eventCallbacks;

    void mapEvent(const EventType type, functionPtr callback) {

        // here i need to map type to callback
        // each type can have multiple callbacks
        // T can have only distinct event types as "key"

        // this i tried but doesn't work

        eventCallbacks[type].push_back(callback);

    }

    ...
}
```

The intended implementation would look something like:

```
EventMapper<SupaDupaClass> mapper;
mapper.mapEvent(EVENT_TYPE_HELLO, &SupaDupaClass::didYouSayHello);
```

etc ...

I really would like to use vector instead of map for easier unique key assignment ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I read you code correctly, you are accessing an uninitialized entry.

You should first initialize the eventCallbacks with empty vectors, something like

eventCallbacks.assign(10,std::vector())

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `std::map` to map the event_type to the vector of callbacks. And consider using `std::function` instead of function pointers for flexibility.

One possible implementation is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

enum class event_type
{
    event_one,
    event_two
};

void func1() { std::cout << "func1" << std::endl; }
class my_listener { public: void func() { std::cout << "my_listener::func" << std::endl; } };

int main()
{
    std::map<event_type, std::vector<std::function<void ()>>> m;

    my_listener lst;
    m[event_type::event_one].push_back(std::bind(&my_listener::func, lst));
    m[event_type::event_one].push_back(&func1);

    // invoke callbacks (may be used in the code that raises events)
    for(auto& kv : m)
    {
        for(auto& f : kv.second) {
            f();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**
You might consider using [Boost.Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/signals2.html) library.